# Declaring variable in do-while loop and outside as random numbers

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have been trying to write code, which makes the machine guess a random number from 1 to 1000.
Because I know how to write it in pascal and python, I tried to write it in java, but I'm stuck now.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1000);
        int count = 0;

        do {
            int answer = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1000);
            count++;
        } while (random != answer);

        System.out.println("Answer: " + answer + " " + "Count: " + count);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that in this line

```
    } while (random != answer);
```

`answer` is not defined.

I am trying to do the loop, until `random` equals `answer`.

The question is, how do I define the `answer` variable as a random changing number, while the variable `random` stays the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `java.util.Random` for random numbers generation. `ThreadLocalRandom` is used in different contexts.

Comment: You should consider using an IDE. An IDE would visually tell you that you have committed such errors at the earliest possible time (without even compiling the source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `int answer` outside of the `do{}while(...)`:

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1000);
    int count = 0;
    int answer;
    do {
        answer = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 1000);
        count++;
    } while (random != answer);

    System.out.println("Answer: " + answer + " " + "Count: " + count);
}
```

Comment: That did the job and makes sense to me! Thanks!